# my array storing the values only until iterations runs..after completing the storing of values and trying to get those values it returns Null values

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my array storing the values only until iterations runs..after completing the storing of values and trying to get those values it returns Null values and tried so many times and so many ways to get the values but there is no use in my attempts...finally i ended up with stack overflow website.i hope my wait ends here

```
 public class RegisterUser extends BrowserInit{

    public String[][] values;

    @Test
    public void register(String Filepath) throws Exception{

        //Clicking Login link in WebPage
        WebElement Login=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='login']"));
        Parent=driver.getWindowHandle();
        act=new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(Login).perform();

        //moving the cursor to element and clicking on the link
        act.click(Login).perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        //after clicking on the link checking is their any new tab is opened
        Set<String> windows=driver.getWindowHandles();
        for(String Child : windows){

            //if it found switch the control to new tab
            if(!Parent.equals(Child)){
                driver.switchTo().window(Child);    
            }
        }
        ExcelDataClass data=new ExcelDataClass(Filepath);
        //Clicking register in dropdown
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='dropdown-toggle']")).click();
        WebElement register=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Secondary_Navbar-Account']/ul"));
        act.moveToElement(register);
        List<WebElement> Register=register.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        for(int i=0;i<Register.size();i++){
            String Linkname=Register.get(i).getText();
            if(Linkname.equals("Register")){
                Register.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("total rows "+data.RowCount);
        for(int row=1;row<data.sheet.getLastRowNum()+1;row++){

            for(int col=0;col<data.sheet.getRow(row).getLastCellNum();col++){
                //this is the for loop where my array stored the values from the sheet using row index and column index
                values=new String[data.sheet.getLastRowNum()+1][data.sheet.getRow(row).getLastCellNum()+1];
                values[row][col]=data.sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();

            }
```

//after the column iteration completed i tried to get the values from array and stored in string by below code, but it returns null values.. i dont know where i am getting error but my array returns null values for the below indexs even it filled with data

```
          String First=values[row][0];
            String Last=values[row][1];
            String Company=values[row][2];
            String Email=values[row][3];
            String Password=values[row][4];
            String CnfPassword=values[row][5];
            String Add1=values[row][6];
            String Add2=values[row][7];
            String city=values[row][8];
            String state=values[row][9];
            String Zip=values[row][10];
            String country=values[row][11];
            String phone=values[row][12];
            String Findus=values[row][13];
            String Mobile=values[row][14];
            driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys(First);
            driver.findElement(By.name("lastname")).sendKeys(Last);
            driver.findElement(By.name("companyname")).sendKeys(Company);
            driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(Email);
            driver.findElement(By.id("inputNewPassword1")).sendKeys(Password);
            js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            js.executeScript("scroll(0,300)");
            driver.findElement(By.id("inputNewPassword2")).sendKeys(CnfPassword);
            driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys(Add1);
            driver.findElement(By.name("address2")).sendKeys(Add2);
            driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys(city);
            driver.findElement(By.name("state")).sendKeys(state);
            WebElement pin=driver.findElement(By.name("postcode"));
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",pin);
            pin.sendKeys(Zip);
            WebElement Country=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='country']"));
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",Country);
             Thread.sleep(2000);
            Select count=new Select(Country);
            count.selectByVisibleText(country);
             Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.name("phonenumber")).sendKeys(phone);
             Thread.sleep(2000);
            WebElement find=driver.findElement(By.id("customfield1"));
             Thread.sleep(2000);
            Select findus=new Select(find);
            findus.selectByVisibleText(Findus);
             Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='customfield2']")).sendKeys(Mobile);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
           WebElement submit=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-large btn-primary']"));
           if(submit.isDisplayed()){
               act.moveToElement(submit);
               submit.click();
           }else
           {
               act.moveToElement(submit);
               wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
               wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn btn-large btn-primary']")));
               submit.click();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in a debugger? Also, you're creating a new array per row, so why do you need a multidimensional array? The row value will always be the same since you wipe it out and create a new array for the next row.

Comment: I made an error in my above comment, I'll post an answer soon with an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new array per column, essentially erasing what was stored before it.

```
for(/*alltherows*/){

    for(/*all the columns */){
        //THIS IS YOUR ERROR!! You're creating a new array, and storing it in values
        values=new String[data.sheet.getLastRowNum()+1][data.sheet.getRow(row).getLastCellNum()+1];
        //Now you're putting a value in one spot on the array
        values[row][col]=data.sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();

    }
    //data access stuff
}
```

The solution is to create your array outside of your for loops. If all of your rows have the same amount of columns you can hard code the row you look at for this:

```
//create a new array before you use it
values=new String[data.sheet.getLastRowNum()+1][data.sheet.getRow(1).getLastCellNum()+1];
for(/*alltherows*/){

    for(/*all the columns */){
        //Now you're putting a value in one spot on the array
        values[row][col]=data.sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col).getStringCellValue();

    }
    //data access stuff... NO LONGER NULL :)!!
}
```

Some further ideas... If you're only accessing the data per row, a multidimensional array is needlessly complicated. Try to figure out if you can change this to a one dimensional data structure to meet your needs. It will save you headaches down the road as well as for anybody else who needs to interpret the code.

Comment: Thank you so much..i got the issue what actually happening... really thank you so much